# Django Search And View more

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have search results in form of table. I want to add a detail page button which can send the id of the result to another function in view.py
so i can query it from database.

```
{% if sr %}
    {% for k,j in sr %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ k.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ k.chromosome }}</td>
                <td>{{ k.gene_id }} </td>
                <td><a href="{{ j }}"> view</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I want to send this `k.id` to another function

```
 def detailed(request):
    return render(request,"search/Detailed.html")
```

so I can again perform a query from database by this `id`

Comment: This post is a good read to get started with listViews and detailView. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since you didn't specify the version of django you're using, I'm going to assume it's 2.x.** The only huge difference between that and more recent versions of 1.x is the urlpatterns. If you're using 1.11, just use the required regex's you need, as described in the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) Either way, the principle is the same.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....
    path('<int:some_id>/', views.detail_view, name='detail_view'),
    # if django 1.11... you would use ([0-9]{4}) in place of the 'int', or for whatever max amount of numbers you'd want to capture... But I will continue for django 2.x.
]
```

**views.py**

```
def detail_view(request, some_id):
    some_object = YourModel.objects.get(id=some_id)
    return render(request, 'detail_template.html', {'some_object ': some_object})
```

**detail_template.html**

```
<p>{{ some_object.chromosome }}</p> 
<p>{{ some_object.gene_id }}</p> 
<p><a href="{% url 'detail_view' some_object.id %}">View details</a></p>
```

Note that the `url` block above has `some_object.id` added to it as an argument AFTER the view it goes to in quotations. This is the easiest way.

You can also acheive the same thing with a model method by using the `reverse('app_name:view_name', args=[arg_1, arg_2, etc)` function, and then call the method with `{{ some_object.your_method }}`. But those arguments would all depend on what your url patterns and functions took.